# More Efficient Frequency Shift + FIR Decimation

Tags: python, frequency, software-defined-radio, decimation, numpy

I am dealing with complex IQ data from a software defined radio. I'd like to digitally shift the spectrum by some amount to center an off-center signal, then decimate down to that signal only. Currently this is my Python code:

```
f0 = -freq
Ts = 1.0/sample_freq
t = np.arange(0.0, Ts*len(sig), Ts)
exponential = np.exp(2j*np.pi*f0*t)

# Center 'freq'
sig = sig * exponential

decimated_signal = signal.decimate(sig, decimation_factor, n = decimation_factor * 2, ftype='fir')
```

This all works fine, however, I'm finding that the shifting code `sig = sig * exponential` and the decimation itself can be quite slow on an ARM machine especially when the length of the sig data is large.

So I am wondering, is there a more efficient way to implement this algorithm in Python? I've seen some implementations creating a FIR bandpass filter instead, and then decimating with that, but I'm unsure how that works or how to implement that with Python/Numpy.

Comment: Here is a great lecture by fred harris which addresses this subject: [Recent Interesting and Useful Enhancements of Polyphase Filter Banks: fred harris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afU9f5MuXr8)

Comment: is the shift always +-half, or quarter, of the sampling rate?

Comment: No the shift could be anything within the bandwidth. After reviewing the video from @Irreducible (thanks!) I think I'm after what's called a polyphase channelizer, but where each channel might not necessarily be the same bandwidth. Are there any good Python examples of Polyphase Channelizers?

Comment: if the channels are different, a polyphase channelizer is not what you need! How many channels do you need to extract at once? (if it's only one channel at a time, a channelizer isn't what you need)

Comment: For now, just one channel, but I need the option for an arbitrary number of channels with varying bandwidths in the future. For an arbitrary number of channels I was thinking of just running the single channel code multiple times, but I see there is possibly a more efficient way of doing it all together?

Comment: OK after playing around a little using what I learned from the video, I've managed to get decently faster code. 

Basically, I create a memoized FIR BPF, pass that as an DLTI ftype to signal.decimate, and THEN perform a final exponential shift on the much smaller decimated signal. Seems to give identical results to shift, then FIR decimate and is about 6-7x faster. Still not sure if I'm missing out on performance somewhere by using signal.decimate (which is actually signal.resample_poly), especially if I plan on decimating more channels.